# If I'm adding a subobject to a mapped knockout viewmodel, how do I call ko.mapping on that?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I have a `Mission()` object which has an `observableArray` `parts` of `Part()`s objects:

```
    function Mission(mission) {
        koMapping.fromJS(mission, {
            'parts': {
                create: function(options) {
                    return new Part(options.data);
                }
            }
        }, this);

        /* PARTS */
        this.parts = ko.observableArray([]);
    }

    function Part(part) {
        koMapping.fromJS(part, {
            include: ['a bunch of properties']
        }, this);
        var p = this;

        // Computed properties and such like here
    }
```

My `Mission()` object is stored as `self.mission = ko.observable(new Mission())` on my global ViewModel.

I also have an `addPart` function where I need some help:

```
addPart = function() {
    // How do I push a new Part() object to the parts array on the mission here?
}
```

What I'd like to know is how, using knockout's mapping plugin, is to add a new Part to each mission, preferably automatically with little manual configuration. Right now, I've tried a bunch of things which did not work or did not pull across the correct properties. What does not work:

```
addPart = function(partToAdd) {
    self.mission().parts.push(new Part(partToAdd));
}

addPart = function() {
    koMapping.toJS(partToAdd, {}, self.mission);
}

addPart = function() {
    koMapping.toJS(partToAdd, {}, self.mission().parts);
}
```

So how am I meant to do so and have it map automatically?

Addendum: it's worth noting I'm using `koMapping` instead of `ko.mapping` here because I've also employed requireJS...

Comment: Your first implementation of `addPart` appears to be working fine, check this [fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/46mstLvm/).

Answer (score 0):

You can do that like this:

```
addPart = function(partToAdd) {
    self.mission().parts(ko.utils.arrayMap(partToAdd, function (part) {
        return new Part(part);
    });
}
```